# Visual Studio 2019 not suggesting UE4 Libraries

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2019, unreal-engine4

Visual Studio 2019 stopped to suggest Unreal Engine 4 libraries. It used to suggest the names of the heather files I could include in the "name_of_the_new_class.h" file. It used to look like this:
[desired state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhuVb.png) (not my personal screen but that how it used to work), now I get this [current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAbwA.png). I reinstalled UE4 and revalidated Visual Studio how do I solve this if that issue is even solvable?
Manually typed in header files work and it will compile and work but why IntelliSense is not suggesting me this .h files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using <> instead of "" works and autocompletion works again.
https://caligari.dartmouth.edu/doc/ibmcxx/en_US/doc/complink/tasks/tuinclud.htm?fbclid=IwAR1YfI-BL1Ub8MW5GRVDV2iafLhaJx086d9IL_mn3XZVCbD0GRSzqAZ1MCw